# How can i make this extension to loop in backgroud all time

Tags: javascript

I have no idea of how to make this run on backgroud, I searched every post and asked chat gpt but i did not manage to get it right

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    
    "name": "csgoroll notificador",
    "description": "Scrap",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "me",
  
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["popup.js","payload.js"],
      "persistent": true
    },


    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "note.mp3",
    "Sin.png"
    ],

    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "notifications",
      "http://*/",
      "https://*/"

    ],
    

    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
  }
```

payload.js

```
function myCallback() {

var result = "";
while (true) {
   var result2 = "";
   var somethings2 = document.getElementsByClassName("currency-value ng-star-inserted");
   for (var i = 0; i < somethings2.length; i++) {
   result2 += somethings2[i].textContent;
   }
   result2 = result2.substring(0, 2);
   if (result2 > result) {
    
   let url = chrome.runtime.getURL('note.mp3')
  console.log(url)

  let a = new Audio(url)
  a.play()
  var result = result2
   }

   else if (result2 < result) {
    
      let url = chrome.runtime.getURL('note1.mp3')
     console.log(url)
   
     let a = new Audio(url)
     a.play()
     var result = result2
      }
   
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result2);

      Thread.Sleep(2);
}
}


myCallback()
```

popup.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });;
});


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('json-content').innerHTML = message;
});
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>csgoroll notificador</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .container {
            min-width: 500px;
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">guita</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="json-content" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <video controls loop src="gitanoporlasredes2.mp4" width="240"></video>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried adding persistent on manifest and it did not work

Please someone tell me what to do and also things that maybe wrong on the code.

i also want to use manifest 3.0 and dont know how to implement it

Comment: Please provide some more details. What commands are you executing to run the code? Do you see your extension in the list of extensions in the Toolbar? If you can see the extension and you click on it does the popup appear?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.